# Accented letters in preg_match

Tags: php

I need a code which will accept a name (last name and first name). Therefore I need it to accept only letters and it should accept accented letters as well (letters like á, č, ť, í, é, ľ, š, ď, ž, ý -> those are Slovak letters). Plus a space between last and first name.

I have already tried some codes I found on this website, but nothing worked as it should.

I want to do a form and if the name is filled bad it will give you a warning. Now I have this code:

```
$mistakes = array();

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) $name = securee($_POST['name']); else $name = '';


    if (!check_lenght_of_name($name)) $mistakes['name'] = 'Name has wrong lenght';
    if (empty($name)) $mistakes['meno'] = 'You didnt fill name';    
    if (!preg_match("~^\p{L}+(?:[-\h']\p{L}+)*$~u", $name)) $mistakes['name'] = 'You used a wrong letter';



}



if (!empty($mistakes)) {
        echo '<p class="mist"><strong>Mistakes</strong>:<br>';
        foreach($mistakes as $mis) {
            echo "$mis<br>\n";
        }
        echo '</p>';

}
```

Here are two functions I use:

```
function securee($wha){
    return trim(strip_tags($wha));
}   


function check_lenght_of_name($n) {
    return substr_count($n, " ") == 1 && strlen(substr($n, 0 , strpos($n, " "))) >= 3 && strlen(substr($n, strpos($n, " "), strlen($n))) >= 4;
```

But the problem is that when I dont fill name then what I get as a warning is 'You used a wrong letter'  but I should have gotten  'You didnt fill name'. The problem is here

```
(!preg_match("~^\p{L}+(?:[-\h']\p{L}+)*$~u", $name))
```

I have already tried several preg_match codes, but nothing works as I want it to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this regex:

```
/^[A-Záčťíéľšďžý]+ [A-Záčťíéľšďžý]+$/i
```

1. `/^[A-Záčťíéľšďžý]+`: Must start with at least one character from the approved character set
2. : Must be followed by exactly one space
3. `[a-zA-Záčťíéľšďžý]+$/`: Must end with at least one character from the approved character set
4. `i`: Case insensitive

For future regex debugging I highly recommend using https://regexr.com/ so that you can write and test your regular expressions really quickly and the site will explain what the regex is doing.

Comment: I used this one and when didnt fill the name the warning says: 'You used a wrong letter' but it should say 'You didnt fill name'

Comment: @dfps12 It sounds like you have a PHP logic issue so if you implement this in the correct location then make sure your error messages are being shown appropriately.

Comment: @dfps12 Your `if()` statements are missing curly brackets `{}` which is a terrible PHP programming style and can quickly lead to mystery logic.